# Recursive function not returning to immediate caller

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I have written a recursive implementation for finding some specific path given some n*n matrix using this [psuedocode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435990/finding-all-paths-in-directed-graph-with-specific-cost) I found on stackoverflow . I have constructed two arrays:

1. path weight array that holds the edge  value going from one vertex in our graph to another (cell matrix to neighboring cells in matrix)
2. an adjacency array for each index in our path weight array

For some reason however my when my recursive function returns it doesn't return to the immediate caller?

My implementation:

```
        // find paths of specific length from our starting cell 1,1
        // when a path is found print it
        // otherwise return? 
        function findPaths(adjMatrix, pathW_array, path, pathWeight, x, y, idx, curpath_idx){
            // set curpath to the current path (an array with storing path weight values)
            var curpath = path; 
            // tempArray with store pathW_array (set cell value to -1 if value has been added to curpath)
            var tempArray = pathW_array; 

            // curValue retruns sum value of our curpath
            if ( (curValue(curpath) == pathWeight) && (Object.keys(curpath).length !=1)){
                for(i = 0; i < Object.keys(curpath).length; i++){
                    console.log(curpath[i]);
                }
                return;
            }if(tempArray[x][y] == -1){
                return;
            }if(curValue(curpath) > pathWeight){
                return;
            }   

            // Did not return, add current cell value to curpath array
            curpath[curpath_idx] = tempArray[x][y]; 
            curpath_idx = curpath_idx + 1;
            // set current cell value in tempArray to -1 because we've added it to current path (do not want to add same cell value multiple times)
            tempArray[x][y] = -1;

            // iterate until i = pathWeight -1 
            for(var i = 0; i < pathWeight; i++){
                if(adjMatrix[idx][i] != -1){
                     // get pathW_array indices for next neighbor cell of current element
                     arrayIndices = neighbor_value(adjMatrix, tempArray, idx);
                     x = arrayIndices[0];
                     y = arrayIndices[1]; 
                     adjMatrix[idx][i] = -1;
                     idx = adjMatrix_idx(x,y);

                    // findpaths from the next cell in the matrix 
                    findPaths(adjMatrix, tempArray, curpath, pathWeight, x, y, idx, curpath_idx);
                    curpath.pop();
                    curpath_idx = curpath -1;
                }   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
findPaths(adjMatrix, tempArray, curpath, pathWeight, x, y, idx, curpath_idx)
```

to

```
return findPaths(adjMatrix, tempArray, curpath, pathWeight, x, y, idx, curpath_idx)
```

Without understanding the rest of the complexity in the function, this 'should' return the recursive return value up the call stack.